# Modificar teste t para parâmetros de regressão linear no R

Tags: r, regressão

Gostaria de saber como posso mudar o teste t em relação aos parâmetros de uma regressão linear no R. Gostaria de testar se b0 = 0 e se b1 = 1.
Geralmente, a saída de uma regressão testa b0 = 0 e se b1 = 0.
Por exemplo, a regressão abaixo

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
y <- c(1.2, 2.4, 3.3, 4.2, 5.1)
reg <- lm(y~x)
```

da o resultado:

```
summary(reg)
Coefficients:
Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.36000    0.11489   3.133 0.051929 .  
x            0.96000    0.03464  27.713 0.000103 ***
```

Então, b0 não é diferente de 0 (p valor = 0.051929) e b1 é é diferente de 0 (p valor = 0.000103 ***). Mas como testar se b1 é diferente de 1? Seria possível?

Answer (score 2):

Com  o `R` base você pode pedir os intervalos de confiança com a função `confint`:

```
confint(reg)
                   2.5 %    97.5 %
(Intercept) -0.005635243 0.7256352
x            0.849756826 1.0702432
```

No caso acima, com um intervalo de 95%, qualquer valor dentro do intervalo de confiança não é "rejeitado" por um teste de hipótese com nível de significância de 5% (então você não rejeitaria que b1 = 1, por exemplo).

Analogamente, qualquer valor fora do intervalo é rejeitado ao nível de significância de 5%. Para alterar o nível de confiança do intervalo, mude o parâmetro `level`. por exemplo, caso queira 99%, `confint(reg, level = 0.99)`.

Caso você prefira fazer um teste específico ao invés de ter o intervalo, um  pacote  que tem funções de conveniência para análise de regressão é o pacote `car`. Entre elas a função `linearHypothesis` é para testes de hipótese. Para testar se o coeficiente de x (b1) é igual a 1:

```
# se o pacote não estiver instalado rode install.packages("car") antes
library(car) 
linearHypothesis(reg, "x = 1")
Linear hypothesis test

Hypothesis:
x = 1

Model 1: restricted model
Model 2: y ~ x

  Res.Df   RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
1      4 0.052                           
2      3 0.036  1     0.016 1.3333 0.3318
```

O p-valor nesse caso é `0.3318`, ou seja, você não rejeita a hipótese, tal como vimos com o intervalo de confiança. A função `linearHypothesis` também aceita qualquer outra restrição linear nos parâmetros. Por exemplo, você pode testar se o intercepto (b0) é igual ao coeficiente de x (b1):

```
linearHypothesis(reg, "(Intercept) = x")
Linear hypothesis test

Hypothesis:
(Intercept) - x = 0

Model 1: restricted model
Model 2: y ~ x

  Res.Df   RSS Df Sum of Sq      F  Pr(>F)  
1      4 0.236                              
2      3 0.036  1       0.2 16.667 0.02655 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Entre outros testes.

PS: sei que aqui não é o local para isso, mas cuidado com a interpretação dos p-valores. Por exemplo, com relação a "b0 não é diferente de zero" , a rigor você não rejeita a hipótese nula de que b0 seja igual a qualquer valor dentro de seu intervalo de confiança (como 0.6), não somente o zero especificamente.

Answer (score 1):

Eu não conheço nenhuma função capaz de fazer isto o R. Em geral, o que se sugere é fazer testes de razão de verossimilhança, que são muito mais gerais e resolvem problemas mais sofisticados, até mesmo em modelos lineares generalizados.

Entretanto, nada nos impede de escrevermos nossa própria função. Afinal, temos que testar as hipóteses

H_0: \beta = \beta_0

H_1: \beta != \beta_0

em que \beta_0 é o valor de referência sob o qual desejamos realizar o teste. Por padrão, o valor de \beta_0 é igual a zero.  A função `TesteCoeficiente`, definida abaixo, implementa este teste de hipóteses para qualquer valor de \beta_0. Basta informar os seguintes valores para a função:

`reg`: o modelo de regressão obtido com a função `lm`

`coeficiente`: o número do coeficiente no modelo de regressão. Para `y = \beta_0 + \beta_1*x`, 1 significa testar `\beta_0` e 2 significa testar `\beta_1`

`h0`: valor da hipótese nula a ser testada. Em geral, este valor é zero

Com isto definido, basta rodar o exemplo abaixo para ver como a função é executada:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
y <- c(1.2, 2.4, 3.3, 4.2, 5.1)
reg <- lm(y~x)

TesteCoeficiente <- function(reg, coeficiente, h0){
  estimativas <- coef(summary(reg))
  estatistica <- (estimativas[coeficiente, 1]-h0)/estimativas[coeficiente, 2]
  2 * pt(abs(estatistica), reg$df.residual, lower.tail = FALSE)
}

TesteCoeficiente(reg, coeficiente=2, h0=0)
[1] 2.771281e+01 1.031328e-04

summary(reg)
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Residuals:
         1          2          3          4          5 
-1.200e-01  1.200e-01  6.000e-02  1.457e-16 -6.000e-02 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.36000    0.11489   3.133 0.051929 .  
x            0.96000    0.03464  27.713 0.000103 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.1095 on 3 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9961,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9948 
F-statistic:   768 on 1 and 3 DF,  p-value: 0.0001031
```

Note que o output da função `TesteCoeficiente` é idêntico ao da função `summary` testando `h0 = 0`. Portanto, a função funciona para este caso particular. É bastante razoável supor que ela funciona para qualquer valor de \beta_0. Agora basta trocar o valor do parâmetro `h0` da função para realizar o teste de hipóteses desejado.